# jQuery fileupload create form dynamiclly and send to s3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

i would like to upload files added through jquery-fileupload via ajax send form. My problem is when i'm trying to overwrite add() function i want to:

1. create db object for file
2. create dynamiclly form
3. attach one file from fileupload to the created form
4. send it via ajax to s3

   ```
   add: (event, data) ->
   # send each file to the s3
   for file in data.files
       $.ajax({
           url: "/attachments",
           data: { ... }
           type: "POST",
           processData: false,
           dataType: "json",
           async: false,
           success: (retdata) ->
               # now when object in db has been created i want to send a file
               s3Data = retdata
               s3Form = $("<form>", {
                   id: "avatar-form",
                   action:  "#{s3Data.schema}://#{s3Data.host}",
                   method: s3Data.method,
                   enctype: "multipart/form-data",
                   acceptCharset: "UTF-8"
               })
               # create inputs for files
               for key, value of s3Data.formdata
                   s3Form.append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"#{key}\" value=\"#{value}\"/> ")

               # here i have my file object from the loop and also access to the
               # data.form, which is jquery file upload form
               # how to extract files from form, and append it to the new s3Form

               s3Form.ajaxForm({})
               s3Form.submit()
   ```

How to copy attached file to one form to the second form ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the input fileupload object maybe accessible via js: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_fileupload.asp However the forms may need to attach to the document first.

Comment: When o get element from DOM, probably beacuse of ht jquery file upload, i don't see files attaached to the input.